# CSV read certain range of row

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have 100 rows of data in CSV file
Let's say I just want to read rows 56 to 62, is there any way I can just type print(row[1 to 9])?

Comment: You would first need to open the file, then extract the data. Did you have any code that you used for this?

Comment: I would interpret `to_csv` as a way to extract the data. It reads in the data from a file and returns it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Python's CSV reader to correctly parse the rows and the [`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=islice#itertools.islice) function to pick just the range of rows you want.

For example:

```py
import csv
from itertools import islice

with open('input.csv') as f_input:
    for row in islice(csv.reader(f_input), 1, 10):
        print(row)
```